# Storing date, time, and timezone in PostgreSQL with Grails and GORM

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I have a Grails 2.5.3 application that is connecting to PostgreSQL, and I want to store a java `Date` or `Calendar` object in the database, and include the time zone.

Based on the [PostgreSQL Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html), the default timestamp type does *not* include time zone, so you need to use the `timestamptz` type to include the time zone.

Unfortunately when I try to set this up in the `mapping` closure of the domain class, it fails. I'm trying to use this:

`createdDate type: 'timestamptz'`

And the error I receive is:

`nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: timestamptz`

Unfortunately the list of [Hibernate types](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-basictypes) does not seem to include anything that would map this value. The ones related to dates are: `date`, `time`, `timestamp`, `calendar`, `calendar-date`. I have tested each of these, and none of them create the desired `timestamp with time zone` in Postgres.

There are articles that talk about creating a custom Hibernate `UserType` for this, but it seems like this would be a fairly common use case, and I can't help but think there is something that should let me get this working out of the box.

Comment: You may be able to store the timestamp and time zone as two separate properties/columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own dialect and then map the Java type to the SQL type. You can see how it's done in the [grails-postgresql-extensions](https://github.com/kaleidos/grails-postgresql-extensions/blob/master/src/main/groovy/net/kaleidos/hibernate/PostgresqlExtensionsDialect.java) plugin and subclass that dialect or just the default postgresql one.

```
package my.company

import java.sql.Types
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import net.kaleidos.hibernate.PostgresqlExtensionsDialect

@CompileStatic
class SQDialect extends PostgresqlExtensionsDialect {

    SQDialect() {
        registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, 'timestamp with time zone')
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much for the help! Quick question. I created my own dialect extending `PostgreSQL82Dialect`, is there a benefit to extending `PostgresqlExtensionsDialect` instead?

Comment: With the plugin you can use postgresl natives types such as arrays, hstore, json and jsonb native types inside your Grails application. You can check the documentation here: https://github.com/kaleidos/grails-postgresql-extensions
Disclaimer: I'm the creator of the plugin. If you use it and have some problems, questions or suggestions feel free to open an issue.